# How to De-serialize reference function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, deserialization

I want to parse the function I get and execute them. I am trying to de-serialize a function's reference I get from my application's state.

There are two types params I get to parse.

**1. Plain function.**

**2. Function's reference from another class.**

For No.1 I got a solution. I use

```
function foo() {
  alert('native function');
  return 'Hello, serialised world!';
}

// Serializing
var serializedFunc = foo.toString();

// Deserializing
var actualFunction = new Function('return ' + serializedFunc)();
```

But for No.2 If I follow the above solution, I get reference error.

```
var actualFunction = new Function('return ' + AppControllerHelper.testFunction)();
```

I get reference error.

[image]

I know the cause of this error. This error occurs because, the deserialized form of the function looks something like this (given below). It can execute the plain function, but when executing a function's reference. It is unable to find the AppControllerHelper inside the scope and so it throws the error.

```
// Case No 1. - Executes the body of the anonymous function when called with no err.
(function anonymous(){
return function() { function foo() { alert('native function'); return 'Hello, serialised world!';} }
})

// case no. 2 - When trying to execute it looks for AppControllerHelper and since not found it throws 
 reference err.
(function anonymous(){
return function() { AppcontrollerHelper.testFunction }
});
```

Could some one suggest me good solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please post the string value of `AppControllerHelper.testFunction`.

Comment: `new Function` always creates a function in the global scope. You could use `eval` if all the variables are available in your current scope, but you cannot restore closures that reference arbitrary free variables. Why are you even trying to this? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @Bergi To give you a background.
We are using redux state in our application, we cannot store the functions in state. Hence we are serializing the function and storing to state.

When retrieving, we need to de-serialize. This is my actual problem

Comment: Not storing functions in state does not mean storing serialised functions in state. Functions should be considered totally non-serialisable (regardless whether they have a `.toString()` method or not). In redux state, use a *data structure* that somehow *represents* what your function should do. So I ask again: what is your actual problem where you need to put something "executable" in your state?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need/want to do that in JS.
Take a look at the ***this*** keyword and how it works in JS and the methods *call()*, *apply()* and *bind()*.

MDN this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

This is an example of manually serializing and deserializing a function:
https://gist.github.com/briancavalier/4a820b32e0d2abca89f7

However, I don't think it's a good option for multiple reasons.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! this was super help. I tried the concept of bind() here. Worked like a charm. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

As @GBra has mentioned, we don't have to serialize and deserialize the functions.

I used the concept of bind() in javascript to overcome my challenge. with the bind() function I can store the function in a variable and use it later.

```
let sampleObject = {
   foo: function() { console.log("this is a test function") }
}

// passing 'sampleObject' as param will put the 'this' to sampleObject.
let bindFunction = sampleObject.foo.bind(sampleObject);

bindFunction();
```

Comment: I don't get how that helps. Functions are already first class members in JavaScript, so you can always store them in a variable or pass them around. Your example doesn't use a `this`, nor does it have any parameters, so `bind` is neither setting `this`, nor are you performing partial application. It's the same as if you had done `let bindFunction = sampleObject.foo`, then calling `bindFunction()` would provide the exact same result.